# SQL group the data on column values (Key, Value)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to group the data in MYSQL but no idea how can I do this.

There was an old table with following data.

```
ID  Product Version     Memory   Color
1   1       iPhone 7    128      Black
2   2       iPhone 7    128      Black
3   3       iPhone 7    32       Gold
4   4       iPhone 7    32       Gold
```

> SELECT count(1), Version FROM old_temp_table GROUP BY Memory, Color,
>   Version

Group Query returns following output:

```
count   Version
2       iPhone 7
2       iPhone 7
```

**Now:** I have converted this table into Key, Values Form, but I want to get same output on group as I have done for old table.

```
ID  Product   Key       Value
1   1         Version   iPhone 7
2   1         Memory    128
3   1         Color     Black
4   2         Version   iPhone 7
5   2         Memory    128
6   2         Color     Black
7   3         Version   iPhone 7
8   3         Memory    32
9   3         Color     Gold
10  4         Version   iPhone 7
11  4         Memory    32
12  4         Color     Gold
```

I have tried the following query:

> SELECT count(*), test_group.`Key` from test_group GROUP BY
>   test_group.key, `Value`

This query shows different output.

```
Count   Key
2       Color
2       Color
2       Memory
2       Memory
4       Version
```

How can I do this in best way? Thanks

**Updated:** I dont want to compare both tables data. I just want to group new table data, but the output should be same as I have done for old table.

```
Version:iPhone 7,Memory:128,Color:Black
Version:iPhone 7,Memory:32,Color:Gold
```

Comment: You've shown the output of several queries, none of which may be the _actual_ output you want.  What output do you want here?

Comment: "I have converted this table into Key, Values Form" I do wonder why :-(

Comment: @Strawberry I am creating aggregator application for e-commerce. So I have different categories of products with different attributes. I am not sure about limit that how many columns I need to create in future.

Comment: I am retrieving same product like iphone 7 from 10+ stores with different price with different attributes, like memory color. I am creating script that will grouped similar products and find cheapest price. If you have any suggestion please let me know. I am not DB oriented guy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sub query to unpivot your table and get results the same as your first query like this. Also you can test it out on **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88017/4)**.

```
SELECT
    Version, Memory, Color, COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT
        Product,
        MAX(CASE WHEN `Key`='Version' THEN `Value`
        ELSE NULL
        END) AS Version
        ,MAX(CASE
             WHEN `Key`='Memory' THEN `Value` 
             ELSE NULL 
        END) AS Memory
        ,MAX(CASE
             WHEN `Key`='Color' THEN `Value` 
             ELSE NULL 
        END) AS Color
    FROM test_group
    GROUP BY Product
) AS PivotView
GROUP BY Version, Memory, Color
```

This will yeild a result like this

```
+-----------+-------+------+-----+
|Version    |Memory |Color |COUNT|
+-----------+-------+------+-----+
|iPhone 7   |128    |Black |2    |
|iPhone 7   |32     |Gold  |2    |
+-----------+-------+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *pivot* your data (not really what your original question implied) then you can try the following:

```
SELECT
    Product,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `Key` = 'Version' THEN Value END) AS Version,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `Key` = 'Memory'  THEN Value END) AS Memory,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `Key` = 'Color'   THEN Value END) AS Color
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Product
```

Note that `KEY` is a reserved keyword in MySQL.  You should not be using keywords to name your columns, tables, etc., but if you do use them, you must escape them with backticks.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Sorry I missed something. I am not looking for old table data. I just want to group new table data but it should be in same way as I have done for old table,

Comment: @AskQuestion Your question wasn't too clear to me, I thought you wanted to unpivot, when in fact it appears you want the _opposite_ of that.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Now renamed the Key Column :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT Count(PRODUCT) [Count], [Version],[Memory],[Color]
    FROM (
    SELECT [Key], PRODUCT, Value
    FROM #test_group) up
    PIVOT (min(Value) FOR [Key] IN ([Version],[Memory],[Color])) AS pvt
    GROUP BY [Version],[Memory],[Color]
```